# Can I disable dynamic dns update during "realm join"?

Tags: sssd, dynamic-dns, realm

When (re-)joining an EL7 system to the AD domain, something somewhere issues a dynamic dns update for $FQDN. How can I suppress that?

The sssd.conf itself is pre-populated with

```
[domain/ad.example.com]
dyndns_update = false
dnydns_iface = eno1, eth0, otherpossibleprimarynicnames
```

I do not suffer from wanton dynamic dns updates during regular operations. But when re-joining the AD domain, all the ethernet cards' IP addresses magically show up in dns, which then causes havoc.

On EL6, I use the `net ads join` which has a nice option: `--no-dns-updates` but I see no equivalent option for the realm command.

If no options come up, I might just fall back to net ads join on EL7 and discard the "new and improved" realmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was simply unable to suppress the dynamic dns update action of realm. I reverted to using `net ads join`

Answer (score 0):

Years (and probably multiple versions) later, I've encountered the same issue. But using dyndns_update = false actually worked for me. That said, I may know what went wrong for the original poster. I've found that sssd is *very* picky about edits to sssd.conf, and when you join a realm, it often uses that realm's defaults instead of what you've indicated. So instead of editing sssd.conf, you need to create an override file in /etc/sssd/conf.d/01-mydomain.conf

The file *must* have the same ownership and permissions as sssd.conf (usually root:root 600) or it will be quietly ignored. The file in question would look something like the section you put above, but simply this:

```
[domain/ad.example.com]
dyndns_update = false
```

To do it cleanly, the best bet is to leave the realm (assuming you've joined it), remove /etc/sssd/sssd.conf completely (back it up, of course), create the override files in /etc/sssd/conf.d, ensure they have the correct ownership and permissions, and re-join the realm.

I have other overrides, some system-wide in 00-sssd.conf and some domain-specific in 01-mydomain.conf -- sssd reads and applies these in sort order.

Important to note that the newly-generated sssd.conf will NOT include these overrides. You have to know to look for them in conf.d; it's not the most user-friendly setup but it seems to work well once you get it sorted.

Comment: Additional note: dyndns_iface applies only when dyndns_update = true, so including it as the OP did may have introduced confusion; best to omit it completely.

Comment: I've tested this on multiple systems (in my case, AlmaLinux) through multiple leave/joins and it seems to work. Even survives a system reboot.